# Save continuous location data on server through android

Tags: android, sql-server, servlets

I am developing an android app wherein I am sending the location of the device to a web service(written in servlets) depending on two parameters(1.specific time interval, 2.distance traveled threshold(send location if distance traveled is more than 10 mtrs)) so as to minimize power consumption. The location will be in terms of latitude and longitude. This latitudes and longitudes will be stored on the server along with the timestamp. I am confused as I don't know what approach to select for saving the data on the server. The data would be continuous and I want to handle it efficiently on both sides, i.e. device as well as server. Should I save the data in database(I am using MSSQL) on the server or save it in a separate file for each device on the server? Which would be the efficient and secure technique? Or is there any other approach available to do the same? After the location details of device are saved on the server, I should be able to retrieve those back and send them again to another device on request. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what all you have tried till now ?

Comment: @Akhil I have a table which stores user data, email id being the unique key. There is another table (I have thought of) which stores location (latitudes & longitudes with timestamp)with primary key of the email id being a foreign key. I am not getting how to save the location with timestamp. Should I update the table each time the location is received from the device? Would it efficient to do this many writes on database?

Comment: what is location update interval ?

Comment: @Akhil 5 mins or traveled distance 10mtrs whichever event occurs first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accumulate some data on device say for one hour, **it will save a lot of power on device(saving power of frequent API calls)**. You can upload these data to your server at once. On server side you can keep your data which suits your business logic.

Comment: but if I do so, within that span of time if user clears app data that the data will be lost.

Comment: yes.. but you don't write app logic for such scenarios..why user will do so ??

Comment: yes but this can happen by mistake..Not necessarily all android users are pro. Some users happen to clear app data frequently to free memory. Just want to be sure.